# Cruisecontrol .net config file not reading changes (ccnet.config)

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net

Does anyone have any insight as to why changes to the ccnet.config file are not being accepted by ccnet?

We have a ccnet.config file that holds about 30 projects.  Usually, if you need the configuration reloaded we can just 'touch' the file and save it, and the ccnet.log shows that ccnet has noticed the config changes and reloads the config with the changes.  Here's an example of it working:

```
2010-02-15 09:33:42,465 [4804:INFO] Config file modification detected for  C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.config
2010-02-15 09:33:42,465 [4804:INFO] Configuration changed: Restarting CruiseControl.NET Server 
2010-02-15 09:33:42,465 [4804:INFO] Reading configuration file "C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.config"
2010-02-15 09:33:42,793 [4804:INFO] Stopping integrator for project: BatchFileExecutor.branch
2010-02-15 09:33:42,793 [4804:INFO] Stopping integrator for project: DeliveriesService.branch
```

However, just now I have done mods to the file, saved it and only gotten the:

```
2010-02-15 09:33:42,465 [4804:INFO] Config file modification detected for  C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.config
```

line and not the evidence of all the config changes being populated.  I've noticed that sometimes if I've broken the XML, the file (quietly! argh!)refuses to load, but I've validated the file using the supplied 'CCvalidator.exe' tool and it checks out OK.

I've tried restarting the ccnet service, as sometimes that does the trick, but not this time.

So right now, ccnet is using the previous version of the config file, and just won't let go of it!  We are using version 1.4.4.83.

Cheers,
Lance

Comment: I eventually got it to load not by restarting the service, but by stopping it for a few minutes and starting it up again.

FYI - Restarting the service took about 10 seconds, but STOPPING the service took a couple of minutes, and it never finished, I got some error about the process not exiting cleanly.  So it seems to me that 'restarting' the service didn't actually restart the service.  Great.

Comment: The more often this happens, the more I think that it's 'stuck' in the way that @Ross has mentioned - ccnet mistakenly thinks that there are still jobs in the queue and won't reload the config.  It seems to happen about once per 20 restarts or so.

Comment: +1 still useful months later when I ran into this issue. Restarting CC was not an option for me, so it's good to know I just had to wait it out :)

Answer (score 12):

It isn't documented, but CC.NET waits for all running builds to stop before reloading the configuration or before shutting down.

Comment: @ross - thanks, I figured that tip out after a while.  It's understandable why it's done, but it'd be nice if the ccnet.log said something like 'config changes detected - waiting until current workload is complete before reloading'